# BLT graph y axis title not clear

Tags: graph, tcl

I can't find the reason as to why the Y-axis title "Counts" doesn't look clear and the X-axis title does look good "Time".

TCL Code:

```
proc graphCreation {} \
{
global backColor
global btnColor
global xtemp yBio yPart tempgraph

    blt::stripchart .tempgraph -width 625 -height 330 -background $backColor -plotbackground white -font boldFont
    set tempgraph 1

.tempgraph configure -borderwidth 0 \
         -leftmargin 0 \
         -rightmargin 0 \
         -plotborderwidth 0 \
         -plotpadx {0 0} \
         -plotpady {0 0}

.tempgraph legend configure -hide yes
.tempgraph grid configure -color gray \
                  -dashes 1 \
                  -minor 0 \
                  -hide 0

.tempgraph axis configure x -command FormatXLabel 
                    #-shiftby 1 \
                    -stepsize 2

proc FormatXLabel {widget x} {
    set xtemp  [expr round($x)]
    return [clock format $x -format "%H:%M:%S"]
}
# Bio
.tempgraph element create Bio -symbol {} -color red -linewidth 1 \
    -smooth linear 

.tempgraph axis configure y -title "Counts" 
.tempgraph axis configure x -title "Time"
}
```

this is how it looks:

[image]

Update: I end up placing a simple image next to the graph replacing the native y-axis label it looks a lot better than native in my situation

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly subtle issue. Alas. BLT does rotated text by rendering the text normally in an off-screen buffer and then rotating the resulting image, pixel by pixel, before transferring the result to the screen. It's quite a quick technique if one applies appropriate caching. (Tk 8.6 uses a similar mechanism for rendering rotated text on a canvas in some configurations — those that can't draw rotated text directly, such as the classic X11 font renderer — but uses a more complex rotation algorithm.)

However, it must be assuming that the buffer is effectively monochrome and that any pixel that is not exactly the background color is foreground. This means that any pixel that was originally shaded at all (for antialiasing/sub-pixel rendering) becomes black after rotation. (You can see “the jaggies” on the rotated text too if you look closely.)

Ugly, isn't it?

The only fix I can suggest — and it's not the greatest — is to run Tk 8.6, embed the graph *without axis titles* in a Tk `canvas`, and to use the canvas's rotated text capabilities to draw on the titles “by hand”. This is because Tk's rotated text code is quite a lot more capable; in particular, on any platform that does antialiased text rendering, it moves the rotated glyph rendering into the system font engine itself, meaning that the antialiasing happens *after rotation* and the text looks right.

(Disclosure: I wrote the rotated text code in Tk. You wouldn't *believe* the bugs I found in various platforms when doing that, particularly with cumulative coordinate rounding errors.)

A workaround would be to use a very thin font. Or disable font antialiasing at the system level…

Comment: There's no chance of a backport of the rotation code to Tk 8.5; it was a lot of work, and touched quite a few internal APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the info, What I end up doing is using a simple image and place it next to the graph, I thought that was the easiest way, but want it to make sure if I was missing something